# Sugar CRM REST API calls over POST always return documentation

Tags: rest, sugarcrm

I am issuing the following login API request (using Fiddler) to a Sugar 6.5.4 server, and all I ever get back with a POST request is the documentation for `SugarWebServiceImplv4_1.php`. I expect to get a JSON response with the session ID (or an error?).

What am I doing wrong?

I have tried the v2, v2.1, v3, v3.1, v4, and v4.1 service URLs; all issue their respective documentation as the response.

**Request**

```
POST https://sugarserver/service/v4_1/rest.php HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Host: sugarserver
Content-Length: 180
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

method=login&input_type=JSON&response_type=JSON&rest_data={"user_auth":{"user_name":"username","password":"md5passwd"},"application_name":"test"}
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 20 Jun 2014 17:39:16 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.5
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 39895

<pre>/**
 * SugarWebServiceImplv4_1.php
 *
 * This class is an implementation class for all the web services.  Version 4_1 adds limit/off support to the
 * get_relationships function.  We also added the sync_get_modified_relationships function call from version
 * one to facilitate querying for related meetings/calls contacts/users records.
 *
 */
Class [ <user> class SugarWebServiceImplv4_1 extends SugarWebServiceImplv4 ] {

...
```

---

**If, on the other hand, I send a GET request, then I get a valid response. Why is POST not working?**

With a POST, I can't move the `rest_data` parameter -- or the raw JSON object without the `rest_data` parameter name -- into the request body, both cause an "Invalid Login" JSON response.

**Request**

```
GET https://sugarserver/service/v4_1/rest.php?method=login&input_type=JSON&response_type=JSON&rest_data=%7B%22user_auth%22:%7B%22user_name%22:%22username%22,%22password%22:%22md5passwd%22%7D,%22application_name%22:%22test%22%7D HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Host: sugarserver
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

**Response**

```
Date: Fri, 20 Jun 2014 20:56:05 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.5
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=redacted; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 967
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html

{"id":"redacted","module_name":"Users","name_value_list"...}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ugh - it was the content-type on the request. It must be set for a URL-encoded form, then a POST request works.

`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`

Answer (score 2):

Try hitting your server over http instead of https and see what that does... otherwise, hit the endpoint with your browser like `https://sugarserver/service/v4_1/rest.php?method=login&input_type=JSON&response_type=JSON` just to see if you get JSON back or what... when I try that on my production server, I get a JSON-encoded error message:

```
{"name":"Invalid Login","number":10,"description":"Login attempt failed please check the username and password"}
```

Comment: Can't use HTTP on our server, must use HTTPS. When I test with your URL (without a `rest_data` parameter), I do get a JSON response. I've updated my post to tweak my question - thanks.